# JAX-RS GET and DELETE giving 405 Error

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have implemented a method to upload an audio file by posting to a Jersey JAX-RS REST backend. This works fine. However, when I try to implement the DELETE audio file method, it gives me the following error:

```
HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed
```

I can't for the life of me see what is wrong - i assume it might be something trivial that I am blind to, as I've done many DELETES before and they have worked. I've also tried to implement a simple dummy GET method and that too gives the same error.

The file upload is done using an angularjs directive called ng-file-upload.
It is uploaded successfully using the following url:

```
file.upload = Upload.upload({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/pododdle/webapi/auctions/' + bid.auction_id + '/uploads?category_id=' + bid.category_id,
    data: {file: file}
});
```

An example URL for the upload would then be:

```
http://localhost:8080/pododdle/webapi/auctions/1/uploads?category_id=2
```

I have tried using POSTMAN to use the DELETE incase my frontend code was wrong. The url supplied was:

```
http://localhost:8080/pododdle/webapi/auctions/1/uploads
```

Here is the code for the entire 'uploads' Resource, both DELETE and POST. As you can see the DELETE is only a dummy method, with no real work done. Also, the upload Resource is a subresource of the 'auctions' resource.

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UploadResource {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(UploadResource.class);
    AuctionService auction_service = new AuctionService();

    @DELETE
    public Response deleteAudio(@PathParam("auction_id") int auction_id) {
        System.out.println("inside deleteAudio");
        return Response.ok().build();
    }

    //this uploads the audio file, stores it to disk, and then saves the file-path to the auction
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces("text/html")
    public Response uploadAudio(@PathParam("auction_id") int auction_id, @QueryParam("category_id") int category_id,
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputString, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileInputDetails) {

        //We need to get the value of the audio root directory
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            properties.load(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("pododdle.properties"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Error getting the audio root directory location when uploading the audio: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String auctionAudio = "audio/category/" + category_id + "/auction/" + auction_id + "/" + fileInputDetails.getFileName();
        String audioFileName = properties.getProperty("audioRootDirectory") + auctionAudio;

        NumberFormat myFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        myFormat.setGroupingUsed(true);

        try {
            File audioFile = new File(audioFileName);
            File parent = audioFile.getParentFile();
            if(!parent.exists() && !parent.mkdirs()) {
                return Response.status(501).entity("Error creating directory when uploading the audio to the server. Please try again in a few moments").build();
            }
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(audioFile, false);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes = 0;
            long file_size = 0;

            while((bytes = fileInputString.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
                file_size += bytes;
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            log.info(String.format("Uploading Audio file for category: " + category_id + ", fileSize: %s", myFormat.format(file_size)));
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("error uploading audio file to server: " + ioe.toString());
            return Response.status(501).entity("Error uploading the audio to the server. Please try again in a few moments").build();
        }

        //now updating the auction with the audio path in the database and return the updated auction
        return Response.ok(auction_service.updateAuction(auction_id, auctionAudio).toString()).build();
    }
```

}

The Auction resource looks like this:

```
@Path("/auctions")
public class AuctionResource {

    //creating sub-resource for auction bids
    @Path("/{auction_id}/uploads")
    public UploadResource getUploadResource()
    {
        return new UploadResource();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not related to your issue but using a `String.format` to finally inject `category_id`  in the middle of your format...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this error was caused by the project not building properly. Upon inspection of the buildpath, it seemed two jar files were mysteriously missing! They were:

```
jersey-media-multipart-2.21.1.jar
mimepull-1.9.3.jar
```

I have no idea how the jar files were deleted from the /lib directory of the glassfish server, maybe I shouldn't have drunk that extra bottle of whiskey. Once they were added back in, everything suddenly worked hunky dory. A little baffled by the error - i would have thought it would give a compile error if the jar wasn't available. Anyhow, 5 days lost due to another annoying error.